# Solace Realtime Distribution using VMR

Tags: solace

Can Solace VMR be used for realtime distribution of Market Data? Let me know your thoughts/suggestions.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Solace is commonly used for market data distribution.

You can go through some examples of the use cases at http://www.solacesystems.com/solutions/financial-services

Also, you might be interested in looking at some of the featured customers
http://www.solacesystems.com/customers